# Convert Image to matrix in R(3.2.1)

Tags: r, image, function, matrix, jpeg

How to convert a jpeg image to matrix in R(version 3.2.1)?(as imagedata function is not available in this version)

Comment: Could you show what you ave tried so far?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+a+jpeg+image+to+matrix+in+R , http://www.bing.com/search?q=How+to+convert+a+jpeg+image+to+matrix+in+R , ...

Answer (score 1):

There is a `jpeg` package. If it's an RGB file then you get three layers (an R array); if greyscale, you get one layer (which would be a matrix).

```
> img <- jpeg::readJPEG("/Volumes/BOOTCAMP/Program Files/HP/Digital Imaging/bin/hpqscimg/ZeroDevice.jpg")
> str(img)
 num [1:470, 1:580, 1:3] 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(EBImage)
im <- readImage("imagen.jpg")
```

The EBImage package is available on Bioconductor.

http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/EBImage.html